# Prevent Variable to get 'None' Value in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have programmed like below in Robot:-

```
@{lines}=   Split to lines  ${contents}             
:FOR    ${line} IN  @{lines}                    
    ${nodename}=    Run Keyword If  ${line_length}== 1  Run Cmd And test Rval2  echo "${line}"  > /tmp/node.txt
```

How do I avoid nodename getting 'None Value'?

Whenever line_length is not equal to 1 nodename is getting a value 'None'.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
${nodename}=    Run Keyword If  ${line_length}== 1  Run Cmd And test Rval2  echo "${line}"  > /tmp/node.txt    ELSE    Set Variable    defaultValue
```